# Magento Adminhtml Grid - Invalid block type

Tags: php, magento, grid, adminhtml

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Cybercon_Certificationverification_Block_Adminhtml_Certificationverificationbackend_Grid' in /home/sbm19/domains/sbm19.saistudy.com/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sbm19/domains/sbm19.saistudy.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/sbm19/domains/sbm19.saistudy.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('cybercon_certif...', Array)
#2 /home/sbm19/domains/sbm19.saistudy.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('cybercon_certif...', 'adminhtml_certi...')
```

Cybercon/Certificationverification/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cybercon_Certificationverification>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cybercon_Certificationverification>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <certificationverification>
                <class>Cybercon_Certificationverification_Helper</class>
            </certificationverification>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <certificationverification>
                <class>Cybercon_Certificationverification_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>certificationverification_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </certificationverification>
            <certificationverification_mysql4>
                <class>Cybercon_Certificationverification_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <certification>
                        <table>cybercon_certificationverification</table>
                    </certification>
                </entities>
            </certificationverification_mysql4>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <certificationverification>
                <class>Cybercon_Certificationverification_Block</class>
            </certificationverification>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <certificationverification>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cybercon_Certificationverification</module>
                    <frontName>admin_certificationverification</frontName>
                </args>
            </certificationverification>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <certificationverification>
                    <file>certificationverification.xml</file>
                </certificationverification>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Cybercon/Certificationverification/Block/Adminhtml/Certificationverificationbackend.php

```
<?php

class Cybercon_Certificationverification_Block_Adminhtml_Certificationverificationbackend extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'cybercon_certificationverification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_certificationverificationbackend';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('certificationverification')->__('Certifications');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

Cybercon/Certificationverification/controllers/Adminhtml/CertificationverificationbackendController.php

```
<?php
class Cybercon_Certificationverification_Adminhtml_CertificationverificationbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("Certification Verification"));
       $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('certificationverification/adminhtml_certificationverificationbackend')->toHtml());
       $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

layout/certificationverification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <adminhtml_certificationverificationbackend_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="certificationverification/adminhtml_certificationverificationbackend" name="certificationverification" />
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_certificationverificationbackend_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: You need to give a better explanation with your code. What are you trying to do? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cybercon_Certificationverification_Block_Adminhtml_Certificationverificationbackend->_blockGroup` has to match the identifier in `config/global/blocks` in your `etc/config.xml`